# How to host my Angular and spring-boot web app

Tags: web-hosting

I was wondering if anyone could help me out. I'm just starting to make a small website for the fun of it but I'm wondering how to host my frontend and backend.

As of now, I brought a domain that is being hosted, and I can put in my frontend dist folders and it runs. But how do I make it so that my backend can also run of this domain?

Are there folders I need to add from my backend or some code I need to run to start up the backend?
If you need more information to help me please ask!

Thanks!

Comment: You would have to serve your project within the spring boot app's static file folder and you would need to configure your project via like I did here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009159/failed-to-decode-downloaded-font-in-angular-5